# Return value of static method of nested model is ignored in parent model (expressjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model in expressjs that has a property which is an instance of another model, basically a nested model, like this:

```
// nested.js
var NestedPropDef = {
  someProp: { type: String, default: '' },
};
var schema = new Schema(NestedPropDef, { minimize: false });
schema.statics = {
  getInstance() {
    var nestedObject = new NestedProp();
    nestedObject.someProp = 'something';
    console.log('[first log] value of nestedObject:', nestedObject);
    return nestedObject;
  },
});
var NestedProp = mongoose.model('NestedProp', schema);

exports.NestedPropDef = NestedPropDef;
exports.NestedProp = NestedProp;
```

```
// parent-file.js
var NestedPropDef = require('./nested').NestedPropDef;
var NestedProp = require('./nested').NestedProp;

var schema = new Schema({
  otherProp: { type: String, default: '' },
  nestedProp: NestedPropDef,
});

schema.methods.updateNestedProp = function (data, callback) {
  this.nestedProp = NestedProp.getInstance();
  console.log('[second log] value of nestedProp:', this.nestedProp);
  this.otherProp: data.otherProp;
  console.log('[third log] value of this:', this);
  this.save(callback);
});
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', schema);
module.exports = Parent;
```

Each of those `console.log` statements yield the following:

```
[first log] value of nestedObject: {
  someProp: 'something'
}
```

So I know the instance of the nested property is being created correctly.

```
[second log] value of nestedProp: {}
```

I don't understand why this is an empty object. For some reason, the value returned by `.getInstance` is not saved to `this.nestedProp`.

```
[third log] value of this: {
  otherProp: 'some value'
}
```

I don't understand why `nestedProp` is completely missing from this object.

So basically I can't figure out why the return value from the static method of the nested object is not getting used by the parent model. Any ideas will be very welcome, thanks!

**Update**: it appears that the bug is linked to using [this JWT](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/) library, though I don't know why. I don't use the library in any routes/code related to this problem. I think they're linked because the bug goes away when I revert to the commit before I installed the JWT library.

**Update 2**: the JWT lib was actually unrelated to the issue, but the problem was introduced with a recent change to mongoose. As of mongoose@5.9.24, the log statements would be as follows (and this is what I want):

```
[first log] value of nestedObject: {
  someProp: 'something'
}
[second log] value of nestedProp: {
  someProp: 'something'
}
[third log] value of this: {
  otherProp: 'some value',
  nestedProp: {
    someProp: 'something'
  }
}
```

I know that I can export the schema of `NestedProp` instead of its definition, and that would *mostly* fix the issue, but it adds the `_id` field to `nestedProp` and that wasn't happening before. In other words, doing this:

```
// nested.js
...
exports.NestedPropSchema = schema;
exports.NestedProp = NestedProp;
```

```
// parent-file.js
var NestedPropSchema = require('./nested').NestedPropSchema;
var NestedProp = require('./nested').NestedProp;

var schema = new Schema({
  otherProp: { type: String, default: '' },
  nestedProp: NestedPropSchema,
});
...
```

causes this:

```
[third log] value of this: {
  otherProp: 'some value',
  nestedProp: {
    someProp: 'something',
    _id: ...
  }
}
```

I know there's a way to disable the automatic addition of the `_id`, but my objective is to restore the previous functionality so that other subtle bugs don't creep up on me. How can I restore the results I was seeing in 5.9.24? Or was I always nesting incorrectly (and Mongoose was just working with my incorrect nesting)?